# link and text on same line using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that looks like, where the web address is on the second line:

**Code in`bash` used to create new.txt**

```
while read A B
do
    echo "https://www.xxxx.com/add_2_cart.php?catno=${A}&storage=lyophilized&rxns=100&num=1&test=mixed&format=tube"
done < inputfile > new.txt
```

**File 1 Contents of new.txt**

```
PXL-A0000005 DTE3504500000005 
web address
PXL-A0000007 DTE3504500000007 
web address
```

I am trying to reformat that file using:

```
 awk '1;getline <"link.txt"' new.txt > newfile.txt
```

but getting the same output and I am not sure why or how to output each on one line:  Thank you :)

**Desired output**

```
PXL-A0000005 DTE3504500000005 web address
PXL-A0000007 DTE3504500000007 web address
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `inputfile`?  I only get the URL with substitution when I run your bash script to create `new.txt.`  I think awk can do what you want with something like `awk '{ print $0 "https..." $1 "end of url" }' inputfile`, but I'd need to see `inputfile` to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use awk ? `paste` should do the job :

```
 paste -s -d' \n' new.txt
```

Results:

```
 PXL-A0000005 DTE3504500000005  web address
 PXL-A0000007 DTE3504500000007  web address
```